# Why @screen xl and @screen lg gets overridden by @screen md in tailwindcss?

Tags: css, media-queries, tailwind-css

I extended tailwind `margin` properties in the config file:

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            'margin': {
                '1/5': '20%',
                '1/4': '25%',
                '1/3': '33.333333%'
            }
        }
    },
    variants: {
        margin: ['responsive']
    },
    plugins: []
}
```

And then applied it in my `css` with the following:

```
@screen xl {
    .content-section.contract {
        @apply ml-1/5;
    }
}

@screen lg {
    .content-section.contract {
        @apply ml-1/4;
    }
}

@screen md {
    .content-section.contract {
        @apply ml-1/3;
    }
}
```

But instead of getting the `margin-left: 20%` on extra large screens and `margin-left: 25%` on large screens, styles gets overridden by the value for medium screens.

[image]

I tried adding `!important` in each styles in different screen sizes but it doesn't work as I expected. I believe this cannot be reproduce in a fiddle, since customize utilities is not supported in [CDN version of tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/#using-tailwind-via-cdn).

Comment: are you sure that your screen is wide enough in this example? I see that the ruler starts from 400. Maybe it's just not large enough to hit 1024px?

Comment: @PavelLint the image was cropped. My screen resolution is 1920 x 1080, and getting the same behavior.

Comment: You can see below the highlighted properties that `width: 80%` for extra large screens are applied, but not the `margin-left` that I created

Comment: I guess `@screen xx` should be translated to `@media (max-width: yyy)`, but not to `@media (min-width: yyy)`.

Comment: Yes, @Kosh is right. According to the image, this is exactly what is happening here. You either have to use `max-width` instead of `min-width` or change the order of your queries, so the smalles screen comes first and the largest last.

Comment: @ArturNoetzel **change the order of your queries** did the trick for me. `Max-width` will do too, but I'm using the given syntax by tailwind which is `@screen xl`..etc. which is using `min-width` by default. If you would like to write that as answer, I'll accept it to help future readers. Thanks BTW.

Comment: @threeFatCat: nice to hear that, always eager to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the image, the order of the queries is responsible for this behavior.

This is because whenever multiple css rules of the same priority apply to an element the last one wins.

In this case here: whenever a screen size reaches the width required by the xl query, the queries for the smaller screens apply as well. Since the medium query is the last one, it overrides the styles of the queries that have been declared before.

A rule of thumb is to sort the queries from smallest to largest when using `min-width` (mobile first).
When using `max-width` (desktop first), it is the other way round.

The solution here is to either use `max-width` instead of `min-width` or change the order of your queries, so the smallest screen comes first and the largest last.

**Example** (reversed order):

```
@screen md {
    .content-section.contract {
        @apply ml-1/3;
    }
}

@screen lg {
    .content-section.contract {
        @apply ml-1/4;
    }
}

@screen xl {
    .content-section.contract {
        @apply ml-1/5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option which can be useful if you want to combine `min-width` and `max-width` in one media query,  and still make use of Tailwind's breakpoints.

For example, you can set these rules to ONLY work on `md` screen sizes, without being propagated to larger screen sizes.

```
@media (min-width: theme('screens.md')) and (max-width: theme('screens.lg')) {
    .content-section.contract {
        @apply my-8;
    }
}
```